# React.JS set new state and use it in same function

Tags: reactjs, setstate, react-state

I was trying to `setState` and use the new value inside of same function.

Functions:

```
  const { setTasks, projects, setProjects } = useContext(TasksContext)
  const [input, setInput] = useState('')

  const handleNewProject = () => {
    setProjects((prevState) => [...prevState, {[input]: {} }])
    tasksSetter(input)
    setInput('')
  }

  const tasksSetter = (findKey) => {
    const obj = projects?.find(project => Object.keys(project)[0] === findKey)
    const taskArray = Object.values(obj)
    setTasks(taskArray)
  }
```

Input:

```
<input type='text' value={input} onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}></input>
<button onClick={() => handleNewProject()}><PlusCircleIcon/></button>
```

I understand, that when we get to `tasksSetter`'s execution my `projects` state hasn't been updated yet. The only way to overcome it, that I can think of, is to use `useEffect`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    tasksSetter(input)
  }, [projects])
```

But I can't really do that, because I would like to use `tasksSetter` in other places, as `onClick` function and pass another values as argument as well. Can I keep my code DRY and don't write the same code over again? If so, how?

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to achieve, where is `handleNewProject` being used? You want to use `projects` inside `taskSetter` even though it wasn't updated yet?

Comment: @Ben updated my question on that matter. I would like to use updated value of `projects` inside `tasksSetter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something you can do when you can't rely on the state after an update.

```
const handleNewProject = () => {
  const newProjects = [...projects, {[input]: {} }];
  setProjects(newProjects);
  tasksSetter(input, newProjects);
  setInput('')
}

const tasksSetter = (findKey, projects) => {
  const obj = projects?.find(project => Object.keys(project)[0] === findKey)
  const taskArray = Object.values(obj)
  setTasks(taskArray)
}
```

We make a new array with the update we want, then we can use it to set it to the state and also pass it to your `tasksSetter` function in order to use it. You do not use the state itself but you do get the updated array out of it and the state will be updated at some point.

Comment: @rey2197 Glad to help, keep on the good work!